Development environment for RPico without USB
Goal: use a microprocessor (most likely RPi Pico, i.e. RP2040) for SDR analysis in combination with RTL2832U (typical rtl-sdr dongle) and output some information on a small LCD display (connected with SPI or I2C).
Since the dongle is usually accessed through USB, so I plan to use RPi Pico USB socket for communication with RTL2832U. Therefore, to upload the code, I plan to use RPi Debug Probe and use SWD Debug and UART Serial instead.
I am looking for the development environment which would fit the best for this. I started to work with Pycharm and uploaded micropython code through USB (after dropping micropython uf2 file). I couldn’t upload the code through the RPi Debug Probe with Pycharm. I also read that debug options for python are limited comparing to C++.
Question: what development environment would you recommend? Preferably on macOS, but I am open to alternatives. I mean not upload once, after typing 1K commands in terminal, but a really convenient environment for serious development.
Somebody say Pycharm is good if you do python, some say CLion if you use C++ while it is integrated gdb and openocd. Somebody claim VS Code fits the best.
Question repeated: did anyone do something like this and can advise from hir own experience? Links to some review articles are also highly appreciated.
Relevant questions, though not answering mine
Debugging micropython code using raspberrypi pico debug probe
VSCODE integration of debugging Raspberry Pico with Debug probe. On MacOS host platform not able to configure
Raspberry Pi Debug Probe fails with `Error: Failed to connect multidrop rp2040.dap0`
Debugging using raspberry debug probe fails with SWD error

Please try a search before asking such a complex question.

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

The document Getting Started with Raspberry Pi Pico pdf linked from the Raspberry Pi microcontroller documentation page has info about this.  It's common to use another pico to act as a debug probe so that the USB port is free for your application.  This setup is document in the document for Linux, Windows, and Mac OS is the document.  I have it setup with VS code and it works well.
